# How to change remote terminal on QNX

Tags: openssh, tty, qnx

How can I change tty when I'm connecting to QNX 6.3.2 through openSSH ?
Screen isn't available.

Comment: Are there any messages on the screen ???

Comment: By screen i mean function. I can connect to tty but when connection get lost, after reconnect I'm getting next tty